# no output when using subprocess.call in gdal?

Tags: python, gdalwarp

I'm trying to clip an image in gdal and when I run this code:

```
gdalwarp -cutline path/to/polygon.shp \
-crop_to_cutline -dstnodata "-9999.0" \
in_raster.tif \
out_raster.tif
```

it runs ok and output is working ok too.
However, when running this code:

```
import ogr
import subprocess

inraster = 'in_raster.tif'
inshape = 'polygon.shp'
outraster = 'out_raster.tif'

subprocess.call(['gdalwarp', '-cutline', inshape, '-crop_to_cutline', '-dstnodata -9999.0', inraster, outraster])
```

it doesn't create any output. I reckon there is something wrong in  `-dstnodata <nodata_value>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split `-dstnodata` and `-9999.0` into two parameters, so that you have

`subprocess.call(['gdalwarp', '-cutline', inshape, '-crop_to_cutline', '-dstnodata', '-9999.0', inraster, outraster])`

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091242/subprocess-call-requiring-all-parameters-to-be-separated-by-commas) post.